# How BDI agent architecture is connected with PSI agent architecture?

Tags: agent-based-computing

How BDI (Beliefs-Desires-Intentions) agent models is connected with PSI agent model http://cognitive-ai.com/ (and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psi-theory)? Is one of the models the generalization of the other? PSI model seems to be more sophisticated but it may lack (at present) all the logical foundations and reasoning services that are available for BDI agents. From the other side - PSI models can be path forward in the development of BDI agents.

Is PSI model acceptable as agent implementation for the serious study projects and research efforts in computer science? Or should I remain with BDI models for the present?